# Table 100% width and height, and image to scale proportionally with css

Tags: html, css

The background to this question is i'm using a html to image converter and using html as a kind of template.

My requirements is i need to produce layouts that are 100% of the browser height and width, can scale a main image to the available space proportionally in css, and switch off certain images and text

My problem is i cant get the main image to scale and fill the remaining space proportionally .

I have a more complete example here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3dbwdsx0/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
<thead><tr>
    <td><img class="header_image" src="some.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="header_image" src="some.jpg" /></td>
</tr></thead>
<tfoot><tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <span class="text">some text</span></td>
</tr>/tfoot>
<tbody><tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img class="main_image" src="main.jpg">
    </td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
 html,body,table {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.main_image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.header_image {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: would flexbox be an option ? else for a table , td cannot really be display:none where elsewhere you have colspan .. I believe both technic would require image in absolute position to reduce its size within the middle container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if image is set in absolute position , html table or flex box would do the job:

- table

```css
html,
body,
table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(148, 0, 211);
  text-align: center;
  /* for table */
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

td.hide {/* do not remove or remove/update also colspan attribute else where */
  width: 0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  display: block;/* for the gap*/
  margin: auto;
}

.header_image {
  height: 100px;/* your example */
}

thead tr td,
tfoot tr td {
  height: 0;/* no worry it will expand */
}

tbody {
  position: relative;
  /* also uses height left avalaible */
}

.main_image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide"><img class="header_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/400" /></td>
      <td><img class="header_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/2254x1860" /></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"> <span class="text">some text</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <img class="main_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/1600">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- flex

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(148, 0, 211);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
header,main,footer {
padding:10px;
}


footer {
  order: 2;/* in case before main in html */
}

main {
  flex: 1;/* use whole space avalaible*/
  position:relative;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.main_image { 
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.header_image {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="hide"><img class="header_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/400" /></div>
  <div><img class="header_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/2254x1860" /></div>
</header>
<!--<footer> <span class="text">layed &amp; and pinned with flexbox</span></footer>-- NOP not here -->
<main>
  <img class="main_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/1600">
</main>
<footer> <span class="text">layed &amp; and pinned with flexbox</span></footer>
```